# In the pants buildtool, what is the difference between 'advanced' options and regular options?

Tags: python, pants

When you run ./pants with no options you get the help:

```
$ ./pants help
Pants 0.0.32 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pantsbuild.pants/0.0.32

Usage:
  ./pants [option ...] [goal ...] [target...]  Attempt the specified goals.
  ./pants help                                 Get help.
  ./pants help [goal]                          Get help for a goal.
  ./pants help-advanced [goal]                 Get help for a goal's advanced options.
  ./pants help-all                             Get help for all goals.
  ./pants goals                                List all installed goals.
```

I noticed you can also see them with the `--help-advanced` flag.

Why are some of these like the following marked `(Advanced)'?

```
(ADVANCED)
--pants-bootstrapdir <dir>
                        Use this dir for global cache. (default:
                        /Users/zundel/.cache/pants)
(ADVANCED)
--pants-configdir <dir>
                        Use this dir for global config files. (default:
                        /Users/zundel/.config/pants)
```

Comment: Does this matter? Advanced help is provided so advanced users can use advanced features to do something advanced with the tool :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advanced options are not intended for use from the command line and are thus not normally displayed in traditional (-h,--help) command line help.  These options are intended to be set once globally for a repository using pants in that repo's [pants.ini](https://pantsbuild.github.io/setup_repo.html) configuration file if they need to be different from the pants standard defaults.  The fact that help for these options destined for `pants.ini` is displayed on the command line is definitely odd and in some sense its a compromise convenience to provide documentation for those options.

So for a small repo with one or two users "advanced" may be more of a misnomer than for a large repo used by many developers.  In the small case, its likely both devs will need to setup or tweak their repo's `pants.ini` in the course of using pants in that repo.  In the large repo case with many developers its more likely few developers will tweak `pants.ini` and so for the average pants user in that sort of repo these options truly are "advanced" and almost never useful.